# targetting two rules at the same time using sass

Tags: sass

I have a circle+arrow next to a text in a CTA button and i'd like both to change color at the same time when hovering over either of them. Right now when hovering over the text the arrow does not change color, not sure how to write the :

```
<div class="cta-div">
  <a class="cta-btn" href="#" role="button">SAVE NOW&nbsp;<i class="fa fa- 
  chevron-circle-right " style="font-size:34px;color:#efd43d; vertical
  -align:middle; padding:0 0 3px;"></i></a>
</div>
```

sass rule:
    .cta-btn, .fa-chevron-circle-right {
        &:hover {
        color: $btn-bkg-hover-color !important;
        }
    }

I have set this up and working in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roob/9Lsjstf7/1/
Any help is appreciated. If this is a duplicate post then please post a link.

Comment: so when hovered on circle/arrow the color of  ctabtn should hcnage...is that what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not hover on them separately - you just hover on the anchor and when you do that you also hover the child so:

```
.cta-btn:hover,  {
  color: #e8e2bb !important;
  .fa-chevron-circle-right {
    color: #e8e2bb !important;
  }
}
```

Not sure about the !important ... left it as you may need it for some reason.

Comment: sorry to reopen, sass is throwing an error even tho the hover effect works. I pasted the code exactly as above and get this: "Please check validity of the block starting from line #25"

Comment: .cta-btn:hover not .cta-btn:hover, ... typo (remove the comma) - was that it ?